# Having problems reading in coordinates for markers from mongo for google maps

Tags: google-maps, angular

I have a mongoose schema that contains the lat and long for markers in google maps.

I GET the information fine and I can display what is stored in the html template using angular2 so the information is arriving. But, what I want to do, is loop through the callback array that was returned and use the lat and long values to add markers to the map.

I think I have the logic correct after messing around with the component but now I dont know how to feed the coordinates into the code for setting up the markers.

Does anyone know how to go about this correctly using typescript?

When I do a console log of the stores after the callback its undefined,

when I log the length its 0 but this is confusing me as the data is appearing in the html with angular and its there when I find it in the mongo shell.

```
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
   stores: Store[] = [];

   constructor(private storeService: StoreService) {}

   ngOnInit() {

        this.storeService.getStores()
            .subscribe(
                stores => this.stores = stores,
                error => console.error(error)
            );
            console.log(stores);

        var ireLatLng = {lat: 53.1424, lng: -7.6921};   
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: ireLatLng
        });

        stores.forEach(onAddMarker(stores.firstName,stores.lat,stores.long) {
            console.log(stores.firstName + "added");
        });

   }

   onAddMarker(name: string,lt: string,ln: string) {
            var myLatLng = {lat: lt, lng: ln};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: name,
            });
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if the output of

```
console.log(stores);
```

Is empty, it's because you're retrieving the mongo results asynchronously. You should try and create the markers when you actually receive them.

Second, even if you had a store array, inside your `onAddMarker` method you don't have access to the local variable `map` you declared in method `ngOnInit`, so you either pass it as a parameter to `onAddMarker` **or** declare it as an instance property.

Third, a [latLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral) object should have numbers as its values, not strings.

All in all, your `ngOnInit` method should look like

```
ngOnInit() {

   var ireLatLng = {lat: 53.1424, lng: -7.6921};   
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: ireLatLng
   });

    this.storeService.getStores()
       .subscribe(
           stores => {
               this.stores = stores;
               console.log(stores);

               stores.forEach(store => {
                  onAddMarker(store.firstName, store.lat, store.long);
                  console.log(store.firstName + "added");
               }
           },
           error => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

your `onAddMarker` method should look like

```
onAddMarker(name: string,lt: string,ln: string) {
            var myLatLng = {lat: 1*lt, lng: 1*ln},
                map = this.map,
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: name,
                });
}
```

Comment: This gives me syntax errors when I try use the onInit, I've tried moving the brackets around but it wont work, when I've tried putting things in subscribe before it gave me problems